# Separate entity or modifier when updating a model for specific users

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm quite new to DDD so apologies if this is well writ but I have struggled to find an answer.

In our domain we have a representation of a 'Normal Shift', e.g. Afternoon: 15.00 - 18.00. It is possible however for shifts to be modified either on specific days of the week (Mon - Sun) or for specific 'Locations'. The end result should be the same shift (Afternoon for example) but with a new time on a specific day / at a specific location.

How should we model these updated shifts? So far we've come to.

1. A common 'Shift' object which can be applied as a Normal Shift and also associated to a day or location.
2. A model to denote the change 'Shift Adjustment'.
3. Unique models for each shift, with some kind of relationship so they can be applied. E.g. 'Location Shift'.

We keep toggling between 1 & 3. 1 seems like a more natural language fit yet 3 feels more complete in that the business logic isn't hiding real facets of the model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the behaviors of a Normal Shift or a Location Shift? Do they have exclusive behaviors? Is Shift it's own aggregate root or an entity/value within a larger aggregate?

Comment: Hey @plalx. They behave in the same way. A normal shift, say 'Morning' runs from 8-10am. A location can 'override' shifts. e.g. change Morning to run from 7-10am. 

Trusting I have the terminology right, I believe that a shift is an entity, as it always exists within another aggregate root - like a 'Location' or a 'Normal working day'.

Apologies for the delay - I didn't receive a notification from sx.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble to understand the purpose of the model. Could you explain the problem your are trying to solve with this model? What is the purpose of those shifts in the problem domain?

Comment: Hi @plalx. People can be assigned activities. Activities either have a specific due time, or a shift. Much like you might be assigned a shift to work in a coffee shop. I guess this particular model is somewhat anaemic, which might be where the problem comes from. It might be that the shift should be expressed as business logic through the other domain models. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, that puts me in context. I may not be an expert in your domain, but Shift and Due Time are very different concepts to me. In the general language I'd say that a Shift is more like a period of time during which you execute work, but a Due time is when you want that work to be delivered. Anyway, Activities have a Shift... what would be so special about a Normal Shift? Why is it important to label the Shift... I'm trying to understand why a Shift cannot just be a simple value object that could represent any period of time within a day.

Comment: Also... do the Shifts have their own identity? Are they shared between Activities? If I'm not mistaken I think that your Normal Shift is actually a prototype from which to create Shifts. Then I'd like to know... let's say I'm creating a Schedule (collection of Shifts?) for an Activity and I'm reusing an existing Schedule lets say Normal Schedule to save some time. If the Normal Schedule changes at some point then should all the schedules created from Normal Schedule be affected by the change?

Comment: @plalx yeah I was thinking of Prototype or Flyweight pattern too. The important thing to determine here is, are "specific" Shifts the result of a computation of a function (Shift, Day, Location) -> SpecificShift, or are they something much less deterministic and more freely / fine-grainedly settable ?

Comment: @guillaume31 I guess it could even be a combination of both where you may have computations, but also the flexibility of fine-grained overrides. We won't know until the OP gives more details ;) BTW... could you send me back your email in chat, I lost it and had a few questions I'd like you to look at!

Comment: Hi Guys - thanks for the input on this. 

As you say, I think the Shift's are probably DTOs. The final presentation of a shift for a particular day, at a particular location is a mix of computation and state.

Comment: To answer your questions:

- Due time and Shifts are separate concepts. A task exists in a particular shift, and is due either at the end of the shift, or some specific time within the shift.
- A normal shift is not special per say. It represents the shift you would see if the week day or location didn't have specific overrides.
- The label is purely presentational.

Comment: @Yan but do shift adjustments obey well-defined policies (hint : pattern name here), e.g. `"Monday morning shifts are 9-12 instead of 8-12"` or can it be the whim of a user who decides to adjust *any* particular occurrence of a shift to *any* time they want ? If the former, how stable are the policies - should a user be able to create a new one dynamically (i.e. without touching the code) ?

Comment: Shifts are set for an organisation by an admin, where the admin sets the normal / common shifts and then sets adjustments for days / locations. Ultimately a set of shifts makes up a day (and from there, a week) so there are business rules which govern how you can adjust them (in making the morning shift start early, the shift before it must also finish early). So yes, your example is quite right. At one stage I had a 'Shift Adjustment' in the model but it felt like an attribute rather than an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think this initially has nothing to do with DDD.  Rather it is about how you represent these *concepts* in your domain model.

You don't state explicitly the behavior you require.  So, I'm guessing you may want to be able to send a message to an appropriate object in your model to get you a shift ... `FindShift(name,[day,location])`. FindShift would return either a default shift, or a custom one if it exists. Providing the day and location might be optional.

One simple way to represent this is as follows:-

[image]

A Shift has an optional day and location.  This solution requires a business rule (a constraint) preventing applicable duplicates.

There are other ways to model this, especially in regards to making "default" shifts explicit.  But it's hard to do so if you don't state the *behavior* required, rather than just a *structural* description.

Comment: Hi @aryeh. Could you explain how 'representing models within a domain' isn't DDD?

In terms of behaviours I need to get. i) All the shifts for a given day at a given location ii) get all the 'default' shifts iii) get all the shifts for a given weekday, without consideration for location. Thank you for the steer though - we'll go back to our design with a focus on _behaviour_ and try not to think about the persistence so much.

Comment: Domain modeling as a concept is independent of, and pre-dates DDD.

Comment: You can add multiple methods to Shifts that calculate, rate, find or assess over each Shift.  This is a common pattern when modeling a "thing" with identity.  Represent the "thing" as two objects.  One representing the "specific thing", and the other representing the "set of all things".